# Equivalence in natural deduction in First-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

**Task**

> $\vdash \exists x (P(x)\lor Q(x)) \iff \exists xP(x) \lor \exists xQ(x) $

**My answer**

If we have $A \iff B$ then $A\vdash B$ and $B \vdash A$.
So I started trying to see if I could prove $B$ from $A$, but in my tests I couldn't prove that. Below is an image of my attempt.

[image: My answer]

Is this correct or am I missing a step here? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**

Would it maybe be possible to replace the $?$ with $Q(u) \space\space\space \space \neg Q(u)$ which would result in $\bot$ and from there I could use RAA?

Comment: I would start out with an informal "proof in words" that convinces you that the tautology is true.  Then, the exercise should become easier, in that you only need to formalize the informal proof.

Comment: So my reasoning is that the quantifier "exists" is used the same way on both sides as well as they are using the same domain so they should be equivalent. I'm having a hard time to formulate a "proof in words" because I'm a bit unsure of how  to do it when I have a $\lor$ connective. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Your attempt goes in the wrong direction because as soon as you try to use $\lor_i$ to prove $\exists x P(x)  \lor \exists x Q(x)$ _without_ additional hypothesis, you get stuck. See my answer, where I use $\lor_i$ under the additional hypothesis $P(x) \lor Q(x)$. In other words, you should invert the order of the rules $\lor_i$ and $\lor_e$ in your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A derivation in natural deduction proving that $\exists x (P(x) \lor Q(x)) \vdash \exists x \, P(x) \lor \exists x \, Q(x)$: 
$$
\dfrac{\exists x (P(x) \lor Q(x)) \quad \dfrac{[P(x) \lor Q(x)]^*\quad \dfrac{\dfrac{[P(x)]^{**}}{\exists y \, P(y)}\exists_i}{\exists y P(y) \lor \exists z Q(z)}\lor_{i_R} \quad \dfrac{\dfrac{[Q(x)]^{**}}{\exists z \, Q(z)}\exists_i}{\exists y P(y) \lor \exists z Q(z)}\lor_{i_L}}{\exists y \, P(y) \lor \exists z \, Q(z)}\lor_e^{**}}{\exists y \, P(y) \lor \exists z \, Q(z)}\exists_e^*
$$

The other direction is quite similar: the last rule of the derivation is a $\lor_e$ whose minor premises are conclusions of $\exists_e$.

In both directions there is no need for RAA.

Comment: Thank you once again!

Comment: Like this ($B \vdash A$)? I realized that I could have made it even more compact. https://imgur.com/a/wRZ6NF6

Comment: @FredrikAndersson - No, your attempt is wrong because you are violating the constraint about free variables in the rules $\exists_e$ on the top.

Comment: Hmmm, isn't the rule the following? https://imgur.com/a/BSrl9Rb

Comment: @FredrikAndersson - Yes but there is a constraint on the free variables of $\psi$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313341/288417) for more details and an extensive discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, u is a free variable that is not bound to the quantifier? So I assume this isn't correct then either? https://imgur.com/a/R4kD5uC

Comment: @FredrikAndersson - Yes,  your attempt is incorrect because $u$ is a free variable in the conclusion of the rule $\exists_e$, which violate the proviso of the rule $\exists_e$.

Comment: Oh I think I get what you mean now. So this should be correct (sorry for the cramped text)? https://imgur.com/a/ClWrwzf

Comment: @FredrikAndersson - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81964/discussion-between-taroccoesbrocco-and-fredrik-andersson).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline (in words) of how you could approach proving that $LHS \vdash RHS$:

Suppose that $\exists x (P(x) \vee Q(x))$.  Then choose a witness $a$ for this existence statement, so that $P(a) \vee Q(a)$.  We then proceed using a proof by cases to show that $(\exists x P(x)) \vee (\exists x Q(x))$.  In the first case, if $P(a)$, then it immediately follows that $\exists x P(x)$, so we can conclude $(\exists x P(x)) \vee (\exists x Q(x))$.  Likewise, if $Q(a)$, then it immediately follows that $\exists x Q(x)$, so we can conclude $(\exists x P(x)) \vee (\exists x Q(x))$ in this case also. $\quad\square$

Comment: I think I understand it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there is something that satisfies P or Q, then there is a case for something satisfying P or there is a case for something satisfying Q.
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))]^1}{a:P(a)\vee Q(a)}~\dfrac{\dfrac{[a:P(a)]^2}{\phantom{\exists x~P(x)}}}{\phantom{\exists x~P(x)~\vee~\exists x~Q(x)}}~\dfrac{\dfrac{[a:Q(a)]^2}{\phantom{\exists x~Q(x)}}}{\phantom{\exists x~P(x)~\vee~\exists x~Q(x)}}}{{\exists x~P(x)~\vee~\exists x~Q(x)}}{^2}}{\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))~\to~(\exists x~P(x)~\vee~\exists x~Q(x))}{^1}$$

---

If there is something that satisfies P then there is something satisfying P or Q.  If there is something that satisfies Q then there is something satisfying P or Q.  In either case the conclusion holds.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\lower{8ex}{[\exists x~P(x)~\vee~\exists x~Q(x)]^1}~\dfrac{[\exists x~P(x)]^2}{\dfrac{\phantom{a:P(a)}}{\dfrac{\phantom{a:P(a)\vee Q(a)}}{\phantom{\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))}}}}~\dfrac{[\exists x~Q(x)]^2}{\dfrac{\phantom{a:Q(a)}}{\dfrac{\phantom{a:P(a)\vee Q(a)}}{\phantom{\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))}}}}}{\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))}{^2}}{(\exists x~P(x)~\vee~\exists x~ Q(x))~\to~\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))}{^1}$$