# Equivalence in Natural deduction in First-order logic 2

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I would want to check with you guys if I've done the following natural deduction correct. The reason being that I haven't gotten any answer sheet for this task.

**Task**

Solve the following with natural deduction.

> $\vdash \exists x\neg P(x) \iff \neg \forall xP(x)$

**Answer**

As earlier posted similar tasks for this to be correct I have to prove $A \vdash B$ and $B \vdash A$, where $A = \exists x \, \lnot P(x)$ and $B = \lnot \forall x \, P(x)$.

$A \vdash B$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/woKow.jpg

$B \vdash A$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYVEU.jpg

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of $\exists x \, \lnot P(x) \vdash \lnot \forall x \, P(x)$ is perfect. However, your attempt for proving $\lnot \forall x \, P(x) \vdash \exists x \, \lnot P(x)$ is wrong, the rule $\forall_i$ on the top is not correctly instantiated because it does not respect the proviso about free variables: indeed, when you apply the rule $\forall_i$, $u$ is a free variable of an undischarged hypothesis, which is not allowed as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313341/288417). (Note that this proviso is crucial to get only correct derivations, otherwise you could prove $\exists x \, P(x) \vdash \forall x \, P(x)$, which is not correct).

A correct derivation of $\lnot \forall x \, P(x) \vdash \exists x \, \lnot P(x)$ in natural deduction is the following:

$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{\lnot \forall x \, P(x) \qquad \dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\lnot \exists x \, \lnot P(x)]^* \qquad \dfrac{[\lnot P(x)]^{**}}{\exists x \, \lnot P(x)}\exists_i}{\bot}\lnot_e}{P(x)}RAA^{**}}{\forall x \, P(x)}\forall_i}{\bot}\lnot_e}
{\exists x \, \lnot P(x)}RAA^*
$$

Note that in this derivation the rule $\forall_i$ is correctly instantiated, since $x$ is not free in the (undischarged) hypothesis.

There is also a derivation using only one instance of the rule RAA, but it is longer and awkward, not really interesting.

Comment: How come you can do $P(x)$ to $\forall xP(x)$ with the same x? I thought the rule was that you had to use a free variable for $\forall$ introduction?

Comment: @FredrikAndersson - The rule $\forall_i$ claims that if $\varphi(x)$ is derivable then $\forall x \, \varphi(x)$ is derivable, _on the proviso_ that the variable $x$ does not occur free in any undischarged hypothesis (see for instance [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/christian.damboeck/ps06/clemente_nat_ded.pdf), p. 32; or Van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://www.springer.com/it/book/9781447145578), 5th ed., 2012, p. 86). The idea is that if you can prove $\varphi(x)$ without any specific assumption on $x$, then $\varphi(x)$ holds for _every_ $x$.